# How Pass data between classes in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I'm starter in flutter .I want to extract value from API response and reuse it in second class as parameter. Here is my function to call API.

Response from API  :

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": " success",
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265255,
                "user_id": 53,
                "boxName": "box12",
                "proprietaire": 21625147147,
                "adress_circulation": "Paris ",
                "gps_lat": null,
                "gps_long": null,
                "status": "normal"
            }
        ]
    },
    "error": [],
    "status": 200
}
```

I would like to extract id value in variable and reuse in second class .

```
Future<UserBox> fetchBoxes() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    var url = Uri.parse(ApiUtil.GET_ALL_BOXES);
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    errorHandler(response.statusCode);
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var data = body['data']['data'];
    List<BoxModel> boxes =
        List.generate(data.length, (index) => BoxModel.fromJson(data[index]));
    final userbox = UserBox()..boxes = boxes;
    return userbox;

  }

  }
```

UPDATE : and this is the main code :

```
  Widget _buildDeletePopupDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Supprimer un box'),
      content: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Voulez vous vraiment supprimer le box"),
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            removeBox();
          },
          /* onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },*/
          child: const Text('Oui'),
        ),
        new TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: const Text('Non'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 20.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 10.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF6F7F8),
                body: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: KBlue,
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                            _addNewBox(context),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    label: Text(
                                      'Ajouter un nouveau box',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      CommunityMaterialIcons.plus,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            FutureBuilder<UserBox>(
                                future: fetchBoxes(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                    case ConnectionState.none:
                                      return Text('no connection');
                                    case ConnectionState.active:
                                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                      return Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                      break;
                                    case ConnectionState.done:
                                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                        return Text('No Boxes');
                                      } else {
                                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                          var userbox = snapshot.data;

                                          //    print(userbox);
                                          //   inspect(userbox);

                                          //  var user = userbox.user;
                                          return Column(
                                              children: List.generate(
                                                  userbox.boxes.length,
                                                  (index) {
                                            final box = userbox.boxes[index];

                                            //   print(box.id);

                                            // box.boxIdentifiant;
                                            return Card(
                                                child: Column(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              children: [
                                                Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      left: 10,
                                                      right: 10,
                                                    ),
                                                    child: ExpansionTile(
                                                      tilePadding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              left: 10),
                                                      title: Text(
                                                        '${box.boxName}',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 18,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .w500),
                                                      ),

                                                      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                                              MainAxisAlignment
                                                                  .spaceBetween,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Text(
                                                              'Identifient :',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF01153D),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            SizedBox(
                                                              width: 20,
                                                            ),
                                                            Text(
                                                              '${box.boxIdentifiant}',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF848586),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 20,
                                                        ),
                                                        Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                                              MainAxisAlignment
                                                                  .spaceBetween,
                                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                                              CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                  .start,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Text(
                                                              'Nom :',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF01153D),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            Text(
                                                              '${box.boxName}',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF848586),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 20,
                                                        ),
                                                        Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                                              MainAxisAlignment
                                                                  .spaceBetween,
                                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                                              CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                  .start,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Text(
                                                              'Propriétaire :',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF01153D),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            Text(
                                                              '${box.proprietaire}',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF848586),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 20,
                                                        ),
                                                        Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                                              MainAxisAlignment
                                                                  .spaceBetween,
                                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                                              CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                  .start,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Text(
                                                              'Adresse :',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF01153D),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            Text(
                                                              '${box.adressCirculation}',
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF848586),
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w400,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 20,
                                                        ),
                                                        Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                                              MainAxisAlignment
                                                                  .spaceEvenly,
                                                          children: [
                                                            IconButton(
                                                              icon: Icon(
                                                                CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                                    .circle_edit_outline,
                                                                size: 30.0,
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFFDEB522),
                                                              ),
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                                showDialog(
                                                                  context:
                                                                      context,
                                                                  builder: (BuildContext
                                                                          context) =>
                                                                      _buildNamePopupDialog(
                                                                          context),
                                                                );
                                                              },
                                                            ),
                                                            IconButton(
                                                              icon: Icon(
                                                                CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                                    .account_edit_outline,
                                                                size: 30.0,
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFFDEB522),
                                                              ),
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                                showDialog(
                                                                  context:
                                                                      context,
                                                                  builder: (BuildContext
                                                                          context) =>
                                                                      _buildPopupDialog(
                                                                          context),
                                                                );
                                                              },
                                                            ),
                                                            IconButton(
                                                              icon: Icon(
                                                                CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                                    .map_marker_circle,
                                                                size: 30.0,
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFFDEB522),
                                                              ),
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                                showDialog(
                                                                  context:
                                                                      context,
                                                                  builder: (BuildContext
                                                                          context) =>
                                                                      _buildAdressePopupDialog(
                                                                          context),
                                                                );
                                                              },
                                                            ),
                                                            IconButton(
                                                              icon: Icon(
                                                                CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                                    .delete_empty,
                                                                size: 30.0,
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFFDEB522),
                                                              ),
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                                showDialog(
                                                                  context:
                                                                      context,
                                                                  builder: (BuildContext
                                                                          context) =>
                                                                      _buildDeletePopupDialog(
                                                                          context),
                                                                );
                                                              },
                                                            )
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 10,
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    )),
                                              ],
                                            ));
                                          }));
                                        } else {
                                          return Text('No Data');
                                        }
                                      }
                                      break;
                                    default:
                                      return Container();
                                      break;
                                  }
                                }),

 void removeBox() async {
    // if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    String boxId = _boxNameController.text;

    boxApi.removeBox(boxId).then((data) {
      //  print(data);
      //  inspect(data);
      if (data != null)
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoxSettings()));
    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
    });
```

UPDATE 2 : BOXMODEL class :

```
class BoxModel {
  int id;
  String boxName;
  int boxIdentifiant;
  int userId;
  // String createdAt;
  // String updatedAt;
  int proprietaire;
  String adressCirculation;
  int gpsLat;
  int gpsLong;
  String status;

  BoxModel(
      {this.id,
      this.boxName,
      this.boxIdentifiant,
      this.userId,
      // this.createdAt,
      // this.updatedAt,
      this.proprietaire,
      this.adressCirculation,
      this.gpsLat,
      this.gpsLong,
      this.status});

  BoxModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    boxName = json['boxName'];
    boxIdentifiant = json['boxIdentifiant'];
    userId = json['user_id'];
    // createdAt = json['created_at'];
    // updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    proprietaire = json['proprietaire'];
    adressCirculation = json['adress_circulation'];
    gpsLat = json['gps_lat'];
    gpsLong = json['gps_long'];
    status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['boxName'] = this.boxName;
    data['boxIdentifiant'] = this.boxIdentifiant;
    data['user_id'] = this.userId;
    // data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    // data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    data['proprietaire'] = this.proprietaire;
    data['adress_circulation'] = this.adressCirculation;
    data['gps_lat'] = this.gpsLat;
    data['gps_long'] = this.gpsLong;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    return data;
  }
}

class UserBox {
  List<BoxModel> boxes;
}
```

how i can extract id value and save it in variable ?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Any error messages? This part might be the problem: BoxModel.fromJson(data[index]). Your data at this point has already been parsed and converted to Map<String,dynamic>. Maybe you need to do BoxModel.fromJson(jsonEncode(data[index]))

Comment: it's works fine . i recieved all data but i cannot exctract (save) id value in extern varaiable to reuse in second class . How i can do that ? @Andrija

Comment: Where are you using this `fetchBoxes` function ?

Comment: fetchboxes can import all boxes from api and display it on screen . each box has id as you see . after that i will create function can delete box by that id .@Nisanth Reddy

Comment: Post the code where you are actually using `fetchBoxes` function.

Comment: I updated the post @Nisanth Reddy

Comment: One thing missing, add your `BoxModel` class. You need to modify the `fromJson` method to solve your issue.

Comment: i posted BOXMODEL class @Nisanth Reddy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232652/discussion-between-lucky-and-nisanth-reddy).

Comment: ok ... @Nisanth Reddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Change your `_buildDeletePopupDialog` method to accept another parameter.

```
void removeBox(int id) async {
```

Then, add another param to your `_buildDeletePopupDialog` method and use it while calling `removeBox`

```
Widget _buildDeletePopupDialog(BuildContext context, int id) {
  ... rest of your code

  onPressed: () {
      removeBox(id);
  },
```

Finally, start passing the `id` while you are calling the `_buildDeletePopupDialog` method,

```
builder: (BuildContext context) => _buildDeletePopupDialog(context, box.id)
```

This should be solving your case.

Comment: Great  @Nisanth Reddy .